# What Booleans params in session_regenerate_id() does?

Tags: php, session

Sorry If I sound too naive, my question is that what actually the `Boolean` values `True` & `False` are used for in `session_regenerate_id()` ,

According to php.net , I could get this explanation,

> **bool session_regenerate_id ([ bool $delete_old_session = false ] )**
>
> **session_regenerate_id()** will replace the current session id with a new
>   one, and keep the current session information.

**delete_old_session**  Whether to delete the old associated session file or not.

So basically when we pass `True` to session_regenerate_id() , it will delete the old Session values associated with this ?

So I tried to test this with the below lines of codes,

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(-1);

session_start();

echo 'Initial Session ID ::'. session_id().'<br>';

$_SESSION['test'] = 'ok'; //set a session value

session_regenerate_id(false); // true or False what  difference does it make ?

echo 'New Session ID with FALSE param during regenaration ::'.session_id().'<br>';

echo 'IS SESSION EXIST ? <br>';

print_r($_SESSION);

echo '<br>';

session_regenerate_id(true); // true or False what  difference does it make ?

echo 'New Session ID with TRUE param during regenaration ::'.session_id().'<br>';

echo 'IS SESSION EXIST ? <br>';

print_r($_SESSION);

echo '<br>';

exit;
```

**Output**

```
Initial Session ID ::2du1rt3c5ou01db2ruvr32qli7
New Session ID with FALSE param during regenaration ::epid6rhi2k9cfthdrh69udqlk1
IS SESSION EXIST ?
Array ( [test] => ok )
New Session ID with TRUE param during regenaration ::4o766kh2g4eae8vlqupnkmmer5
IS SESSION EXIST ?
Array ( [test] => ok )
```

In my case I can see `True or False` doesn't change the behavior of session values that are set , it only changes the id of `session`.

Is something wrong with my code or Understanding ?

**Edit 2 :** And what is the proper way if I want to initialize a session (first time when user visits) with my own session id( custom generated) ?

Something like this approach ?

```
    session_start();
    //Create new session without destroying the old one
      session_regenerate_id(false);

   //Grab current session ID and close both sessions to allow other scripts to use them
      $newSession = session_id();
      session_write_close();

   // Set session ID to the new one, and start it back up again
      session_id($newSession);
      session_start();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken from here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-regenerate-id.php

> bool session_regenerate_id ([ bool $delete_old_session = false ] )
>
> ```
> delete_old_session
>
> Whether to delete the old associated session file or not.
> ```

it deletes old file that associated with session. it means session does not destruct, it just deletes old file.
for destruction: session_destroy() or just empty $_SESSION = [];

If Your site has high-loads I recommend You to use apc, memcache, redis for sessions and forget about files. Because operation with files gives IO loads on disk drive of server.

```
ini_set('session.save_handler', 'memcache'); // memcache
ini_set('session.save_handler', 'mm'); // shared memory
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply

Answer (score 4):

Reference is talking only about session file.

So if you pass TRUE to `session_regenerate_id()`, the session file (managed by PHP somewhere in temp / session directory) will be deleted immediately instead of waiting for garbage collection.

Comment: Gosh I could I miss that ! Thanks

Comment: Is there any downside to passing true? Seems like we would always want to clean up the old session if we know it to be expired.

Comment: @Nathan The downside to passing true is any concurrent request for the same session (using the old id) might fail because the data has been deleted.  If a user has 2 tabs open to the same page/site, for example, one will have the old session id and you might not want it to be lost yet.